# Android reflection - Find inherited classes

Tags: java, android, reflection

I want to create a list of all the names of the classes that Inherited from some super class.

For example: `class A`, `class B extends A`, `class C extends A`, `class D`. And if I search all the classes that inherited from `A` I will get a list that contains {B,C}.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case of wrong assumptions embedded into a question. Java does not have the idea of a finite set of classes that make up a project, so you cannot ask for their subset.